# Outer product approximation of the Hessian

Tags: machine-learning, hessian

On p251 of Bishop's machine learning book, the Hessian for least squares is derived (as a preliminary step to the outer product approximation):

> $ E = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left(y_n - t_n\right)^2$
>
> $H = \nabla \nabla  E = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \nabla y_n \left(\nabla y_n\right)^T + \sum_{n=1}^{N} (y_n - t_n) \nabla \nabla y_n $

- Firstly, why is the Hessian not given by $\nabla \nabla ^T  E$?
- Secondly, could someone please explain how the full expression for the Hessian is obtained?

Comment: In the book I don't see an explicit transpose as in $(\nabla y_n)^T$.

Comment: @Gilles you must be reading a pre-2009 edition (missing transpose is in errata list). The above is as written in the corrected 3rd printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think the use of the operator is applying $\nabla$ operator twice, one time and one time again on the function $E$. But ... It is often written confusingly as $\nabla^2$, and in this case is $\nabla\left(\nabla E\right)$. Or since $\nabla$ is a vector, $\nabla\nabla^T$ can work as a matrix operator on $E$, but you're just applying the $\nabla$ operator twice.

For the expression, you have: 
\begin{align}
H &= \nabla \left(\nabla  E\right) = \nabla\left[\nabla \left(\frac 12 \sum_{n=1}^{N} (y_n - t_n)^2\right)\right]\\
 &= \nabla \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} (y_n - t_n) \nabla y_n \right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \nabla y_n \left(\nabla y_n \right) + \sum_{n=1}^{N} (y_n - t_n)\nabla \left(\nabla y_n\right)
\end{align}

I still don't get why Bishop has the transpose in his latter printings.