# Confusion about the Hessian approximation

Tags: neural-networks, fisher-information, hessian

There are two popular forms of the neural network Hessian approximation in the literature:
$$
H \simeq \sum_i \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial w_i}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial w_i}\right)^T
\quad 
H \simeq \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i}\right)^T
$$
First one approximates the Hessian via outer product of the Jacobians, and the second one is called *Fisher* approximation.

$y$ is the output of NN and $L$ is the value of loss function.

The origin of the first is simple to undertstand (see [Outer product approximation of the Hessian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193460/outer-product-approximation-of-the-hessian)). The term $(y_n - t_n)$ is small close to the optimum and one neglects it.

The second one originates from the *Information theory* and general expression:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x, y \sim p(x, y)} \left[\nabla_w \log(y | x, w) (\nabla_w \log(y | x, w))^T\right]
$$
And with the substitution $\log(y | x, w) = -L(y, f(x, w))$ one derives the second formula (replacing the true Fisher by empirical approximation):
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x, y \sim p(x, y)} \left[\nabla_w L (\nabla_w L)^T\right] =
\frac{1}{n} \sum_i \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i}\right)^T
$$
Here loss function is evaluated on a single sample.
Intuitively the statement is the follows.
$$
Hessian \simeq Variance \ of  \ the \ gradient
$$
However, it is not clear, when this approximation is valid.

Seems like there is some confusion in the literature. Recent review https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.00554 says, that the authors of the OBS method (Hassibi and Stork) use the Fisher approximation. But according to the original paper (https://authors.library.caltech.edu/54981/1/Optimal%20Brain%20Surgeon%20and%20general%20network%20pruning.pdf) first form of approximation is used.

If the gradient in the Fisher form was calculated on the whole batch, these two approaches would produce entirely different results, since
$$
\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i}\right) = \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right) \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial w_i}\right) = 
(y_n - t_n)
\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial w_i}\right)
$$
Actually, this Hessian would vanish for well optimized model, and it is crucial, that the batch is small, I suppose.

Under what conditions, these two formulas are likely to produce close results?